# how to deliver ADF desktop application forms to user

Tags: java, oracle-adf

how to deliver ADF Desktop Application to user to run on his pc Without IDE ... I tried to deploy it but jar file produced not run as it in NetBeans .. I Use Jdeveloper to use ADF advantages in project . So How to Distribute this app By Jdeveloper ?!!

Comment: You have to host it in a JEE server

Comment: how is that , you mean weblogic , don't understand

Comment: Yes weblogic or jboss, etc.

Comment: and then can i download it or something and get files and deliver , or end user has to go to url of deployment  ?!

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a tutorial site.  There are many tutorials (and the vendor documents) that detail all this.

Comment: Are you talking about a Swing based app, or a web based ADF app? Web Based requires a WebLogic server into which you deploy an EAR. Swing app will be a jar file you create.

Comment: yeb that is i want to .. i can create jar file but unlike netbeans , exeutable jar file not run  although my jre updated or same version

Comment: did someone test app like this ?!